# Select top N from group records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to list the frist record when price is changed. Using below example.

Invoice table records (group by customer with price and sorted by date)

```
Index  Customer Date         Price
01     A        May-01-2016  $12.00
02     A        May-11-2016  $12.00

03     A        May-21-2016  $13.00
04     A        May-22-2016  $13.00
05     A        May-23-2016  $13.00
06     A        May-24-2016  $13.00

07     A        Jun-01-2016  $14.00
08     A        Jun-11-2016  $14.00
09     A        Jun-21-2016  $14.00
10     A        Jun-25-2016  $14.00

11     B        May-02-2016  $12.50
12     B        May-12-2016  $12.50

13     B        May-22-2016  $13.50

14     B        May-24-2016  $13.80
15     B        May-26-2016  $13.80
16     B        May-28-2016  $13.80

17     B        Jun-02-2016  $14.60
18     B        Jun-12-2016  $14.60
19     B        Jun-22-2016  $14.60
20     B        Jun-26-2016  $14.60
```

I need to get the first record when price is changed.  the result will be:

```
01     A        May-01-2016  $12.00

03     A        May-21-2016  $13.00

07     A        Jun-01-2016  $14.00

11     B        May-02-2016  $12.50

13     B        May-22-2016  $13.50

14     B        May-24-2016  $13.80

17     B        Jun-02-2016  $14.60
```

Further to the query, can I limited the result to the latest 2 records for each customer?  the result will be:

```
03     A        May-21-2016  $13.00

07     A        Jun-01-2016  $14.00

14     B        May-24-2016  $13.80

17     B        Jun-02-2016  $14.60
```

Thank you.

Comment: What specific version of SQL Server are you using? Some window functions require 2012+

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:

```
SELECT id, customer, dte, price
  FROM (SELECT id, customer, dte, price
              ,COALESCE(LAG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY id), price - 1) AS prev_price
          FROM invoice) x
  WHERE x.price <> x.prev_price
  ORDER BY x.id
```

Second part:

```
SELECT id, customer, dte, price
  FROM (SELECT id, customer, dte, price
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY id DESC) AS row_num
          FROM (SELECT id, customer, dte, price
                      ,COALESCE(LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY id), price - 1) AS prev_price
                  FROM invoice) x
          WHERE x.price <> x.prev_price) y
  WHERE row_num <= 2
  ORDER BY id
```

Comment: `lag()` seems like the best solution to me.

Comment: Indeed a nice solution if the lag function is available.

Comment: What it will be if it is Access sql?

Comment: @YellowLarry Access does not have any window functions, so you would have to be creative and use several nested queries, or do it in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT * , 
  CAST(SUBSTRING([Date], 5,2) + '-' 
                + LEFT([Date] , 3) 
                + '-' + RIGHT([Date] ,4) AS DATE) AS DateDt
FROM Invoice)
,CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Price , Customer ORDER BY DateDt ASC) rn
FROM CTE
)
SELECT [Index] ,Customer, [Date] ,Price
FROM CTE2
where rn = 1
ORDER BY Customer , DateDt
```

### Result Set

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦═════════════╦═══════╗
║ Index ║ Customer ║    Date     ║ Price ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬═════════════╬═══════╣
║    01 ║ A        ║ May-01-2016 ║ 12.00 ║
║    03 ║ A        ║ May-21-2016 ║ 13.00 ║
║    07 ║ A        ║ Jun-01-2016 ║ 14.00 ║
║    11 ║ B        ║ May-02-2016 ║ 12.50 ║
║    13 ║ B        ║ May-22-2016 ║ 13.50 ║
║    14 ║ B        ║ May-24-2016 ║ 13.80 ║
║    17 ║ B        ║ Jun-02-2016 ║ 14.60 ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩═════════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the date column is in some valid dateformat (otherwise you should convert it), here's another way to do it:

```
;with cte as (
    select 
       Invoice.[index], Invoice.Customer, Invoice.Date, Invoice.Price, 
       rn = row_number() over (partition by Invoice.customer order by date desc) 
    from Invoice
    join (
       select Customer, price, min(date) min_date 
       from Invoice 
       group by Customer, price
    ) t1 on Invoice.Customer = t1.Customer and Invoice.Date = t1.min_date
)
select [index], Customer, date, price 
from cte where rn <= 2 order by [index]
```

Also, *index* is a reserved keyword and as such a bad choice for a column name.

With your sample data the output would be:

```
index   Customer    date        price
3       A           2016-05-21  $13.00
7       A           2016-06-01  $14.00
14      B           2016-05-24  $13.80
17      B           2016-06-02  $14.60
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bcd22/3)

If you're using SQL Server 2012+ you can use windowed aggregate functions and do this query which might be more efficient (or not):

```
select [index], Customer, date, price 
from (
    select *, rn = dense_rank() over (partition by customer order by min_date desc) 
    from (select *, min(date) over (partition by customer, price) min_date from Invoice) a
) b where rn <= 2 and Date = min_date order by [index]
```